# How to input int in list and get to sort by first element is second element(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I will try input int at the list for sort it.
the result as I want the first element isn't the most negligible value
(If you see the name, it's weird. don't be surprised)

```
def koko(a):
    return a:a[1]

n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
a = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:n]
a.sort(key = koko)
print('Sorted list:', a)
```

when I input

```
0 1 1 3 2 5 2
```

The results as I wanted:

```
1012235
```

but it error

```
Type error int object is not subscribable
```

Comment: `a = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").split())); a.sort(); a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]; print('Sorted list:', a)
`

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana The error is obvious enough. `list.sort` calls the key function `koko` on the elements of `a`, which are of type `int`, but `koko` tries to apply `[1]` to its argument, which produces the `TypeError`

Comment: It may be obvious to you, but a new programmer who stumbles across this question in the future would be better served by having all the information in front of them.

Comment: I see you have edited the error message. Now it is even less like the full error traceback.